# Magento 2.2.4 - Order header status is different than detail section

Tags: order-status, magento2.2.4

I'm getting a weird error in one of my orders where the header status is processing but order details are all cancel. Can anyone give me a SQL command that I can use to update the table status for the orders tables?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this one:

```
UPDATE sales_order SET status = 'your status' WHERE increment_id = '000000670' ;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. My problem was way beyond what I thought as it was created by the payment gateway plugin which made a mess of the status in various tables. Anyway all is fine now. Thanks for you help.

Comment: you're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You should update the tables `sales_order` and `sales_order_grid` as Amit Bera said.
In `sales_order` you need to update the state column too in order to have consistent data.
So the correct SQL statement for updating the `sales_order` table is (assuming you want to cancel the order):

```
UPDATE sales_order SET status = 'canceled', state = 'canceled' WHERE increment_id = '{ORDER_INCREMENT_ID}';
```

You should check before if the related data in `sales_order_item` table is consitent (i.e. qty_canceled is set)

Answer (score -1):

There are main two tables where Magento store order status.

- `sales_order`
- `sales_order_grid`

So, you have to two queries for an orders

> ```
> UPDATE sales_order SET status = {ORDER_STATUS_CODE} WHERE increment_id = '{ORDER_INCREMENT_ID} ';
> UPDATE sales_order_grid SET status = {ORDER_STATUS_CODE} WHERE increment_id = '{ORDER_INCREMENT_ID}' ;
> ```

*{ORDER_INCREMENT_ID}  means 000001,00000670.*

Comment: Thank you. I'm making progress buy now I'm left with the order items showing it's canceled. :(

Comment: Alex Lim, this query is not proper for all case, Magento different logic   on  order process. Cancel and complete and close is not support for this query,

Comment: Thanks Amit. I jumped into CPanel and used phpMyAdmin to dissect the structure myself. It looks like there is more than meets the eye.

In sales_order table, there are 2 columns which are state and status as well as sales_order_grid table which has a status plus sales_order_items which has qty_canceled too. 

Managed to edit the records and get everything fine now. Your post is of great help to get me started.